# (CRON) error (can't fork)

Tags: cron

Ubuntu 16.

```
sudo crontab -e
* * * * * uptime >> /www/w100/log/uptime.log
```

But nothing happens (uptime >> /www/w100/log/uptime.log work's fine).

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
May 20 21:39:01 cs25795 CRON[28233]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
```

Why my cron is so buggy? (

Comment: You should check your system, "can't fork" means the process could not be created (forked).

Comment: In my case, `systemctl status cron.service` showed way to many processes hanging

Answer (score 2):

If you see the `(CRON) error (can't fork)` message, it means that:

- your system is running out of memory
- `cron` can't create the process (due to high memory)

For example, I have a server running with 4 GiB of RAM (3.70 GiB usable), `cron` wasn't able to start other jobs. I checked my memory using `htop` and it shown 3.26 GiB used.

What you can do is find out which process is taking up all the memory (using for example `htop`), kill it and disable it ; or you can just reboot your system. (in my case it was a bot that used over 1 GiB)